# How to translate lambda expressions to the TSQL statement

Tags: t-sql, c#-3.0, lambda

e.g.

```
x => x.UserId > 5 &&
     x.Name.StartWith("S") &&
     x.Name.EndWith("D") &&
     x.Name.Contains("x")
```

to

```
it.UserId > 5 And it.Name like 'S%' And it.Name like '%D' And it.Name like '%x%'
```

Comment: +1 I've been wondering the same.

Answer (score 0):

Rob Connery did it with Subsonic, and Subsonic is open sourced.

Some docs can be fond on [Subsonic site](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/IQueryable) and Subsonic code is [here](http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0)